# auto-scale vms are not picking up jobs in azure scalesets?

Tags: azure, azure-servicebus-queues, docker-container, azure-vm-scale-set

I have a scaleset in azure which will run docker containers inside by grabbing messages from service bus queue. When I spin up the scale-set it is running containers and grabbing messages from queue but when it met the threshold it is scaling vms but those scaled vms are not running containers inside. It is scaling based on the very same images used for initial vm and every vm is identical to each other based on the image used. So if my initial vm is doing the job why not the scaled vms ? Looks like all the jobs are running in one vm which is weird. Any help on this ?

Thx,
kumar

Comment: Could quite understand the issue. Do you mean when scale-set is running messages are retrieved, but when scale-set is scaled out based on some criteria, additionally spinned up instances don't receive any messages? Do you get any errors or anything else that is logged?

Answer (score 0):

> but those scaled vms are not running containers inside.

Have you configure docker containers in the VM image?

Azure VM scale set will use Azure VM image to create new VM instances, if you have not configure docker container in that image, new VM instances will not run docker containers.

> So if my initial vm is doing the job why not the scaled vms ?

We can create a new VM and configure docker container on it, then use that VM to create a new image, use this image to deploy Azure VMSS.

Comment: Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let me know if you would like further assistance.